# Почему неделю называют НЕДЕЛЕЙ?

Tags: этимология

В продолжении обсуждения о том, почему время, которое мы проводим в работе и труде стали называть "НЕДЕЛЕЙ". Хотя само слово говорит об обратном. Выяснили, что последний день, т.е. воскресенье, называли "неделей", день, когда ничего не делают. Так почему же стали называть НЕДЕЛЕЙ всё рабочее время?

Answer (score 3):

У всех славян неделей издавна называли воскресный день, потому что в этот день отдыхали. Но в какой-то момент лет 400 назад в русском языке произошел сдвиг. Неделей стали называть седмицу = семь дней недели, а для последнего дня седмицы подобрали (не знаю почему, пусть ответят историки языка) слово "воскресенье".

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, "неделя" - от слова "не делать". И этим словом изначально называли один день - воскресенье. По-украински оно и сейчас - "недiля". То есть, шесть дней Бог и, соответственно, человек, работал, а один день, седьмой, отдыхал.
Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да с этим как раз и разобрались! А вот КТО ПОСМЕЛ и ПОЧЕМУ все остальные дни,когда "в поте лица"... назвать НЕДЕЛЕЙ?????

Comment: (Гипотеза) Когда люди отмеряли интервалы времени "от недели до недели", это название перешло на сам интервал - подобно тому, как мы сейчас отмеряем расстояния "остановками" городского транспорта (дотуда езды столько-то остановок, пешком далековато идти). Видимо, нашему мышлению свойственен такой перенос наименований.